# getServerSession not return full session variables NextJS13

Tags: session, next.js13, next-auth

i'm using next-auth 4.24.5 in my NextJS 13 website. I have stored username,email,user_id,slug in my session variable after successfull login. All session variables getting correctly in client side pages and in server side pages getting only user email.

app\api\auth[...nextauth]\route.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { loginAction } from "@/utilities/AuthActions";

const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        // Add authentication providers as needed (e.g., Credentials, Google, etc.)
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {

                const response = await loginAction({ email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password });

                if (response.status && response.data.length > 0) {
                    const user = {
                        id: response.data[0].id,
                        username: response.data[0].username,
                        email: response.data[0].email,
                        slug: response.data[0].slug,
                        currency: "INR"
                    };

                    return user;
                } else {                    
                    return null;
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    jwt: {
        encryption: true, // Enable encryption (recommended)
        signingKey: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SIGNINKEY, // Set the private signing key
        encryptionKey: process.env.NEXTAUTH_ENCRYPTIONKEY, // Set the private encryption key
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login', // Redirect to your custom login page
        error: '/error', // Redirect to the custom error page
    },
    session: {
        jwt: true, // Use JWT sessions for better customization       
    },
    callbacks: {       
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            session && (session.user = token.user);           
            return session;
        },
        jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
            user && (token.user = user);            
            return token;
        }

    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

module.exports = { GET: handler, POST: handler };
```

in my Layout.js session wrapper added like this

```
<body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
```

my page.js

```
import HomePage from "@/components/homeComponents/layout";
import {authOptions} from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"; 
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

export default async function Home() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);    
   console.log('session'+JSON.stringify(session,null,2));
  return (
    <>
      <HomePage />
    </>
  );
}
```

when i console the session in home page, i'm getting only the below

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

but in client side getting all the below in session

```
{"user":{"id":"3","username":"test","email":"test@gmail.com","slug":"test","currency":"INR"},"expires":"2024-01-22T04:46:55.854Z"}
```

tried force page reload, pushing custom variables to session etc.., but the same thing always returned.

Comment: Did you log your `cb`'s what is returning?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by changing the export method:

```
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```